# -webkit- para apps

Tags: app, webkit

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para android e iOS, e neste eu preciso usar o -webkit-. Minha dúvida é se eu posso de fato usar o -webkit- para o app sem problemas. 
Obs: o app não é pela internet.

Comment: Eu não estou usando.